# Forward to a new php page

Tags: php

I have the following code which logs someone in to my page - what I am trying to figure out is how to adjust it so that once it has validated that they are a good login, it forwards them to a different page.

```
session_name('wpLogin');
// Starting the session

session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
// Making the cookie live for 2 weeks

session_start();

if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['wpRemember']) && !$_SESSION['rememberMe'])
{
    // If you are logged in, but you don't have the wpRemember cookie (browser restart)
    // and you have not checked the rememberMe checkbox:

    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    // Destroy the session
}


if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}

if($_POST['submit']=='Login')
{
    // Checking whether the Login form has been submitted

    $err = array();
    // Will hold our errors


    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
        $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

    if(!count($err))
    {
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

        // Escaping all input data

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM tz_members WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));

        if($row['usr'])
        {
            // If everything is OK login

            $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

            // Store some data in the session

            setcookie('wpRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);
        }
        else $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
    }

    if($err)
    $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    // Save the error messages in the session

    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
```

Comment: Check the documentation for the `header` function.

Comment: if I change the header at the bottom, wont that change where the page goes if they enter the wrong user/password as well?  That is why I have not simply changed the header.

Comment: Well, all you need to do is to 'protect' it with an `if`. Please check my answer. Do you want the page to go to a different page if the login failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `header` function. The documentation can be found here: http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php

In short, use this:

```
if($row['usr']) {
    // If everything is OK login

    $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

    // Store some data in the session

    setcookie('wpRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Please remember, that ANY `header` function can only work if it's called BEFORE there's a single sign output to the browser.

That includes `echo` or anything outside of the PHP tags. Also, please take care, that your source files don't have a BOM in it's formatting, since that would cause `header` to fail too.